# Trigger function to roll a dice

Tags: javascript, dispatch

I have a function to get a random value (1->6) to roll a dice:

```
const rollDice = () => {
  document.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('rollDice', {
      detail: { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 },
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: false
    })
  );
};
```

Get the value from rollDice() and put in the correct positions, but I don't know why it work incorrectly. The result need show as the picture:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq9Ep.gif)

I am newbie here, Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong?

```js
const rollDice = () => {
  document.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('rollDice', {
      detail: {
        value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
      },
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: false
    })
  );
};

let btn = document.querySelector("#roll-button");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var varones = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#ones p").textContent));
  var vartwos = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#twos p").textContent));
  var varthrees = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#threes p").textContent));
  var varfours = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#fours p").textContent));
  var varfives = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#fives p").textContent));
  var varsixes = toNumber(parseInt(document.querySelector("#sixes p").textContent));
  rollDice();
  document.addEventListener('rollDice', (e) => {

    alert(e.detail.value);
    if (e.detail.value == 1) {
      varones = varones + 1;
    }
    if (e.detail.value == 2) {
      vartwos = vartwos + 1;
    }
    if (e.detail.value == 3) {
      varthrees = varthrees + 1;
    }
    if (e.detail.value == 4) {
      varfours = varfours + 1;
    }
    if (e.detail.value == 5) {
      varfives = varfives + 1;
    }
    if (e.detail.value == 6) {
      varsixes = varsixes + 1;
    }
    total = varones + vartwos + varthrees + varfours + varfives + varsixes;

    document.querySelector("#ones p").textContent = varones;
    document.querySelector("#twos p").textContent = vartwos;
    document.querySelector("#threes p").textContent = varthrees;
    document.querySelector("#fours p").textContent = varfours;
    document.querySelector("#fives p").textContent = varfives;
    document.querySelector("#sixes p").textContent = varsixes;
    document.querySelector("#totals p span").textContent = total;
  });
});

function toNumber(a) {
  if (isNaN(a)) {
    a = 0;
  }
  return a;
}
```

```html
<h1>Events Triggered and Emitted</h1>

<h2>Dice Rolls</h2>

<div id="rolls">
  <div id="ones">
    <span class="dice">&#9856;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="twos">
    <span class="dice">&#9857;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="threes">
    <span class="dice">&#9858;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fours">
    <span class="dice">&#9859;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fives">
    <span class="dice">&#9860;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sixes">
    <span class="dice">&#9861;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dice">
    <button id="roll-button"><span class="dice">&#9858;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="totals">
    <p>Total rolls: <span>0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Template for dice roll 1 -->
<template id="template1"><span class="dice">&#9856;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 2 -->
<template id="template2"><span class="dice">&#9857;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 3 -->
<template id="template3"><span class="dice">&#9858;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 4 -->
<template id="template4"><span class="dice">&#9859;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 5 -->
<template id="template5"><span class="dice">&#9860;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 6 -->
<template id="template6"><span class="dice">&#9861;</span></template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand all your code, but I think you should write your rollDice event listener out of you click button event listener, because in your example, the event is triggered before the document is listening to this event.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // do something
   rollDice()
})

document.addEventListener('rollDice', () => {
   // do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks you @GasparCdv. Thank you. It seems to be working fine, the main problem here is probably because I don't quite understand how dispatchEvent() and CustomEvent work in the existing rolldice function. Now I will try to optimize my code to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't type more code than necessary inside an `eventListener`. If you had refactored your code into a method, you would see that you tried to create an event listener inside an event listener. Here is how an eventListener should be set up:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', rollDice);
```

I don't understand why you created an event listener inside `rollDice()`. Was that part of an assignment? I just called the correct method straight away.

The second part I did was to try to reduce code by looking at similarities in the code. I can use the `:nth-child` selector to get the proper dice container by using the randomized roll.

```
rollsDiv.querySelector(`div:nth-child(${roll}) > p`)
```

The third thing to remember, is to write as short methods as possible, by having them do at most one thing. If you can't do that, try to write methods as a table of content. A person should be able to read the code and understand what's happening just by how it's written. That means refactor complex code, like `getCorrectDiceElement()`, or using variables and naming them to make each row comprehensible.

These are more tips for intermediate coding, but it could be nice to know this on beforehand. Otherwise, you won't understand your own code when looking at it after a half year. :)

As a present, I added a four more lines (a, b) for functionality that I guess you would like to implement in the future. Good luck!

```js
const rollsDiv = document.getElementById("rolls");
// const totalsDiv = document.getElementById("totals");  // a
const btn = document.getElementById("roll-button");
// var numberOfRolls = 0;  // a

const randomize = (max = 6, min = 1) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
};

const rollDice = () => {
  var roll = randomize();
  
  let diceElement = getCorrectDiceElement(roll);
  let previousNumber = toNumber(diceElement.textContent);
  // let diceSymbol = document.getElementById("template" + roll).textContent;   // b
  
  // console.log(roll, diceElement.parentNode.id)

  previousNumber++;
  // numberOfRolls++;  // a
  
  diceElement.textContent = previousNumber;
}

const getCorrectDiceElement= (roll) => {
  return rollsDiv.querySelector(`div:nth-child(${roll}) > p`)
}

function toNumber(a) {
  return isNaN(a) ? 0 : a;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', rollDice);
```

```css
#rolls {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#rolls > div,
#roll-button
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

#rolls p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dice Rolls</h2>

<div id="rolls">
  <div id="ones">
    <span class="dice">&#9856;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="twos">
    <span class="dice">&#9857;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="threes">
    <span class="dice">&#9858;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fours">
    <span class="dice">&#9859;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fives">
    <span class="dice">&#9860;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sixes">
    <span class="dice">&#9861;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="dice">
    <button id="roll-button">Roll</button>
  </div>
  <div id="totals">
    <p>Total rolls: <span>0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Template for dice roll 1 -->
<template id="template1"><span class="dice">&#9856;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 2 -->
<template id="template2"><span class="dice">&#9857;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 3 -->
<template id="template3"><span class="dice">&#9858;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 4 -->
<template id="template4"><span class="dice">&#9859;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 5 -->
<template id="template5"><span class="dice">&#9860;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 6 -->
<template id="template6"><span class="dice">&#9861;</span></template>
```

[EDIT] Added back the original rollDice() method.

```js
const rollsDiv = document.getElementById("rolls");
// const totalsDiv = document.getElementById("totals");  // a
const btn = document.getElementById("roll-button");
// var numberOfRolls = 0;  // a

const randomize = (max = 6, min = 1) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
};

const rollDice = () => {   // NEW
  let eventName = "rollDice";
  let eventDetail = {'value': randomize()};
  let eventProperties = {detail: eventDetail, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false};
  let customEvent = new CustomEvent(eventName, eventProperties);
  
  document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
};

const handleDiceResult = (event) => {
  var eventDetail = event.detail;  // NEW
  var roll = eventDetail.value;
  
  let diceElement = getCorrectDiceElement(roll);
  let previousNumber = toNumber(diceElement.textContent);
  // let diceSymbol = document.getElementById("template" + roll).textContent;   // b
  
  // console.log(roll, diceElement.parentNode.id)

  previousNumber++;
  // numberOfRolls++;  // a
  
  diceElement.textContent = previousNumber;
}

const getCorrectDiceElement= (roll) => {
  return rollsDiv.querySelector(`div:nth-child(${roll}) > p`);
}

function toNumber(a) {
  return isNaN(a) ? 0 : a;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', rollDice);

document.addEventListener('rollDice', handleDiceResult);   // NEW
```

```css
#rolls {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#rolls > div,
#roll-button
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

#rolls p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dice Rolls</h2>

<div id="rolls">
  <div id="ones">
    <span class="dice">&#9856;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="twos">
    <span class="dice">&#9857;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="threes">
    <span class="dice">&#9858;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fours">
    <span class="dice">&#9859;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fives">
    <span class="dice">&#9860;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sixes">
    <span class="dice">&#9861;</span>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="dice">
    <button id="roll-button">Roll</button>
  </div>
  <div id="totals">
    <p>Total rolls: <span>0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Template for dice roll 1 -->
<template id="template1"><span class="dice">&#9856;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 2 -->
<template id="template2"><span class="dice">&#9857;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 3 -->
<template id="template3"><span class="dice">&#9858;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 4 -->
<template id="template4"><span class="dice">&#9859;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 5 -->
<template id="template5"><span class="dice">&#9860;</span></template>

<!-- Template for dice roll 6 -->
<template id="template6"><span class="dice">&#9861;</span></template>
```

Comment: @GasparCdv Yes, thank you, it's kind of like a homework assignment where I have to use the rolldice() function in an existing file. That's why I don't know how to use it properly. Surely it would be easier if I wrote the rolldice() function myself, I really don't understand much about dispatchEvent() and CustomEvent in such a function.

Comment: Thanks you so much @Rickard Elimää. It's true that my code looks very messy, I'm just starting to learn javascript and still have a lot of confusion in using the DOM tree and functions. Here I have to use a rolldice function in the existing file, so I haven't had time to optimize the code yet.

Comment: I see. I added back the original RollDice, but I broke it down into explanatory variables. Hope that clears things up. Had to change the code a bit, but added `NEW` to those rows. You can find new code at the bottom and on the first row in `handleDiceResults()`. You can read more about events over at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events